# Which one is bigger? $2011!$ or $1006^{2011}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, factorial

I want to know Which one is bigger ? $ 2011!  \text{ or } 1006^{2011} $. Any proof with logic is most appreciable.

Comment: See question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523529 about proving that $n!≤ \left(\frac{n+1}2\right)^n$ by induction.

Comment: Got it . Thanks

Comment: Proofs without logic are hardly ever appreciable.

Comment: Why is the canonical answer of this duplicate itself a duplicate?