# Prove $n!≤(\frac{n+1}2)^n$ using AM-GM inequality.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, factorial

The following is what I've done, but I feel it is too simple.  There must be some lapse in logic I'm not seeing.

Proof:

By the AM-GM inequality, $$\sqrt[n]{n!}≤\frac{1+2+...+n}n=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}2}n=\frac{n+1}2$$
Since $\sqrt[n]{n!}≤\frac{n+1}2$, this implies that $n!≤(\frac{n+1}2)^n$.

I've looked at this thread, [Proving that $n!≤((n+1)/2)^n$ by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523529/proving-that-n%E2%89%A4n1-2n-by-induction), and the proof with $i\cdot(n+1-i)≤(\frac{n+1}2)^2$ did not make sense to me.  I did not see how it used the AM-GM inequality, or how it showed $n!≤(\frac{n+1}2)^n$

Comment: Your proof is fine, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992056/how-can-i-show-that-n-leqslant-fracn12n.

Comment: The argument you mention *is* the AM-GM inequality tor two elements(GM² $\le$ AM²).