# Is $ \sqrt{2000!+1}$ a rational number?

Tags: number-theory, rational-numbers

Is $
\sqrt{2000!+1}$  a rational number?
This may seem trivial, but as I wrote $2000!+1=n^2$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, I realised that it probably is not a rational number and that I cannot build a constructive proof, because $n^2-1>2^{2000}$ as from here [Prove by induction that $n!>2^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111146/prove-by-induction-that-n2n)
and also, as $n!<(\frac{n+1}{2})^{n}$ [$n! \leq \left( \frac{n+1}{2} \right)^n$ via induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76130/n-leq-left-fracn12-rightn-via-induction) and  $n^2-1<(1001+\frac{1}{2})^{2002}$ and these are already extremely hard tot tackle. Any help, please?

Comment: According to http://oeis.org/A146968 the only values of $n$ with $n < 10^9$  such that $n!+1$ is a perfect square are $n=4,5,7$.   I think it's reasonable to expect that these are the only such values, but that seems to be open.

Comment: What does probability have to do with anything here? as in "I realised that probably it is not a rational number"

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What probability?

Comment: There's also a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem), quoting recent results that improve the bound to $10^{15}$.

Comment: Just a remark, a rational number is $\frac{n}{m}$. Hence, the proof by contracdition should begin with $$2000!+1 = \frac{n^2}{m^2}$$

Comment: @NN2: Why? It's clearly an integer, so $m=1$ and can therefore be omitted.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork it was a manner of speaking. It simply didn`t look like an usual square.

Comment: This is a purely computational problem, and can be solved purely computationally. The only integers with rational square roots are squares. Then to determine this, it suffices to compute the square root of $2000! + 1$ with enough precision (it seems that 3000 digits is enough, as I just did it on my machine). Or alternately, find the two bounding square numbers that surround $2000! + 1$, which can be done using only big integer arithmetic and a bisection-type algorithm.

Comment: @Troposphere Indeed. Although the advantage of OEIS over Wikipedia is that I arrived at that page by just knowing that 4!+1 and 5!+1 work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A rational number is $\in \Bbb Q$ and is equal to $\frac{n}{m}$

Comment: @davidlowryduda as this might sound primitive and possibly silly, the problem poser requires a mathematical proof rather than a computer-assisted proof.

Comment: @NN2: Yes, I know what is a rational number. But a rational number is the square of an integer if and only if it is an integer.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ok, you can prove it, but this result $\sqrt{n} =\frac{a}{b} \implies b = 1 $ is not something evident.

Comment: @Nate: True -- and I did find the Wikipedia article because OEIS told me the _name_ of the problem. It's a case of synergy between the sources, not a competition :-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a proof that can be done by hand, though certain steps are simplified by having a computer.

1. First, note that $2003$ is prime. (You could check this by noting that no primes below $50$ divide it).
2. It follows from Wilson's Theorem that $2002! \equiv -1 \bmod 2003$. We then also have that
   $$ 2000! \equiv -1 \cdot (2002)^{-1} (2001)^{-1} \bmod 2003, $$
   and $2002^{-1} \equiv 2002 \bmod 2003$ (as this is just $-1$). A bit more work, perhaps using the extended Euclidean algorithm, shows that $2001^{-1} \equiv 1001 \bmod 2003$. Thus
   $$2000! \equiv 1001 \bmod 2003.$$
3. We thus have that $$ 2000! + 1 \equiv 1002 \bmod 2003.$$ If we could show that $1002$ is not a square mod $2003$ (it's not), then we'll be done. To do this, we can use quadratic reciprocity. Namely we consider the Legendre symbol
   $$ \left( \frac{1002}{2003} \right) = \left( \frac{2}{2003} \right) \left( \frac{3}{2003}\right) \left( \frac{167}{2003} \right). \tag{1}$$
4. As $2003 \equiv 3 \bmod 8$, we know that $2$ is not a square mod $2003$. This is the first symbol.
5. For $3$, we use quadratic reprocity. The sequence of steps goes
   $$
   \left( \frac{3}{2003} \right) = -\left( \frac{2003}{3} \right) = - \left( \frac{2}{3} \right) = 1.
   $$
   Thus $3$ is a square mod $2003$.
6. For the last one, the sequence of steps goes
   $$
   \left( \frac{167}{2003} \right) = - \left( \frac{2003}{167} \right)
   = -\left( \frac{166}{167} \right),
   $$
   which we should recognize as asking if $-1$ is a square mod $167$. As $167 \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, it's not a square. Thus $167$ is a square mod $2003$.
7. We can now conclude. The line in $(1)$ evaluates to
   $$ -1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 = -1,$$
   and thus $2000! + 1$ is not a square mod $2003$. And thus it's not a square.

---

Ravi Fernando pointed out an observation that gives an enormous simplification in the comments. The observation is that $1002 \cdot 2 \equiv 2004 \equiv 1 \bmod 2003$, and thus $1002 = 2^{-1} \bmod 2003$. Thus $1002$ is a square if and only if $2$ is a square (mod $2003$). As $2003 \equiv 3 \bmod 8$, $2$ is not a square, and thus $1002$ is not a square.

Comment: You can save a lot of work by noting that $1002 = 2^{-1} \pmod{2003}$, and therefore 1002 is a square if and only if 2 is.  A similar idea simplifies step 2
$$2000! \cong -1 \cdot (-1)^{-1} \cdot (-2)^{-1} \cong 2002 \cdot -1 \cdot -1/2 \cong 1001 \pmod{2003}.$$

Comment: @RaviFernando That is an excellent observation.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thank you for this beautiful answer!!! I accepted it!

Answer (score 13):

We know that $2003$ is prime.
So, by Wilson's theorem, $2002! \equiv -1 \pmod{2003}$

$2002 \equiv -1 \pmod{2003}$.

As such, $2001! \equiv 1 \pmod{2003}$

We can use the Euclidean algorithm to get that $1001 \cdot 2001 \equiv 1 \pmod{2003}$

As such $2000! \equiv 1001 \pmod{2003}$

Which means that $2000! +1 \equiv 1002 \pmod{2003}$.

We want to prove that $1002$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $2003$.

To do that we'll use the law of quadratic reciprocity.

$\left(\frac{1002}{2003}\right) = \left(\frac{2}{2003}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2003}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{167}{2003}\right)$.

$\left(\frac{2}{2003}\right) = - 1$ because $2003 \equiv 3 \pmod8$

$\left(\frac{3}{2003}\right) = -\left(\frac{2003}{3}\right) = -\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right) = 1$ because both $3$ and $2003$ are congruent to $3$ mod $4$.

$\left(\frac{167}{2003}\right) = - \left(\frac{2003}{167}\right) = -\left(\frac{-1}{167}\right) = 1$ because both $167$ and $2003$ are congruent to $3$ mod $4$.

$\left(\frac{1002}{2003}\right) = -1$ which means $2000! + 1$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @Quessema That's the idea I had too (I just didn't have time to finish the quadratic reciprocity law computations), another way to find that $1001 \cdot 2001 = 1 (\mod 2003)$ is to note that $2 \cdot 1002 = 1 (\mod 2003)$ and $2001=-2 \rightarrow 1/2001=-1/2 = -1002=1001$.

Comment: Ah, another with the same proof. It turns out this takes me at least 5 minutes to write out.

Comment: @davidlowryduda You did take more time doing the careful formatting and elaborating the steps. +1 from me.

Comment: Some (...) deleted my answer, a vote to undelete would be appreciated.

Comment: @IgorRivin sorry I don't have enough reputation yet

Comment: No problem, thank you!

Comment: @Oussema this is ok so I upvoted it. You wrote a good answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I hope this doesn’t get downvoted but I’ll write it down nonetheless: it can be computed (wolfram did it) that $2000!+1$ is congruent to $371$ mod $2017$ and $2017$ is a prime. But $371^{1008}$ is $-1$ mod $2017$ (again, by wolfram), so that $371$ is not a square mod $2017$, and thus $2000!+1$ cannot be a square (and rational square roots of integers are integers, which completes the proof).

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but you will admit that your computation is a lot more complicated than mine :)

Comment: It takes more lines and is far more ad hoc, sure. :) But at least we know exactly what’s under the hood (though I’m now unsure how good that is anyway because no one will reproduce this computation).

Comment: "What is under the hood"? I can only hope you are joking.

Comment: @Mindlack I have a similar idea. Please check out my answer.

Comment: @Igor Rivin: wait, you mean that Mathematica just computes the decimal expansion and checks whether there’s a nonzero digit?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @Mindlack it is a good observation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Mathematica,

`IntegerQ[Sqrt[2000!+1]]` returns `False`, so you are good.

**ADDENDUM** For those who think there should be a cute "human" proof, read
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Brocard%27s_problem

Comment: I'm not the downvoter. However, Mathematica can be wrong; I have already seen such cases. Moreover, this is not a proof.

Comment: @Ooussema That IS a proof. As for "mathematical can be wrong" - true, but not for arithmetic.

Comment: @IgorRivin Not a very insightful proof, however

Comment: @IgorRivin Hi Igor. I didn't downvote your answer. However, it is not a proof. It is rather an observation. A proof would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula It IS a proof. Just as to prove 17 is not a square you take its square root, so for $2000!+1.$ If you had the time, you could do it yourself (it does not take THAT long.

Comment: Also, it's not _difficult_ to write a program for oneself that does enough bignum arithmetic from scratch to verify the claim that $a^2 < 2000!+1 < (a+1)^2$ for some concretely given $a$. It doesn't have to be particularly efficient bignum arithmetic for these sizes -- so just use base 10 -- and finding an $a$ to input into the program can be done with standard software, which we _don't need to trust_ as long as it happens to produce the $a$ that works.

Comment: If what one seeks is just the answer. Then I absolutely agree. But sometimes the point is to learn how to tackle a problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand why this answer was deleted. I've undeleted this answer. I've also cleaned some of the comments on this answer. I should also note that the OP did not specify that they wanted a general proof, but instead only asked about the particular case of $\sqrt{2000! + 1}$. This is easily answerable by direct computation, and this answer is one particular direct computation.

Comment: @IgorRivin Your answer should not be deleted. It is a good observation and a solution using the computer. It is valid and I upvoted it. However, I accepted another one, a "paper and pencil" one, but your answer is good too and it should stay. It is an alternative and a note. Thank you very much!